# Crystal Reports Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have created a windows Form application in Visual Studio 2008 and now I have Installed Visual Studio 2012. But my crystal Reporting is not working After searching net for days on the internet I have Done following things but still my Application is not working.

1. I have changed my target framework from dotnet3.5 to dotnet4.
2. I Installed SAP crystal reports for  Studio 2012 and included the reference of `CrystalDecisions.Data.AdoDotNetInterop`

   but After that I got following Error

   The type or namespace name 'CrystalReports' does not exist in the namespace 'CrystalDecisions' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
   The type or namespace name 'ReportSource' does not exist in the namespace 'CrystalDecisions' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

and 26 other errors as well all of them are about  missing a using directive or an assembly reference
3.  After that I commented out my old references than I got Following Errors

```
The type or namespace name ReportClass could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

And 24 other Errors all are about missing a using directive or an assembly reference.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like vs 2012 doesnt found references Try manually  go to solution explorer in (usually right side in vs) right click in refereces in your project and find crystal report in list for 
Assemblies->Solution or Assemblies ->Extensions select references thus add it to project

Or try this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/178150/The-type-or-namespace-name-CrystalDecisions-could) or [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/161248/Crystal-Reports-Problem-with-namespaces-and-refere)

Comment: I tried to include the references but there were no CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine or CrystalDecisions.ReportSource the problem is still there I also visited your suggested links but unable to solve my problem thanks for reply

Comment: I have reinstalled visual studio 2008 and every thing is working fine in visual studio 2008 but not in 2012 version

Answer (score 0):

Download it from https://www.dllme.com/getfile.php?file=14667&id=2782e6dde4bb52c4f71bab7c429b4091

And add references by right clikcking on references folder in your visual studio.

Brows it from the downloaded location.

It's working for me.
Regards!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).